# Punctuation inside quotes: Should I put the period inside quotes, if the sentence ends with a question mark or an exclamation point?

Tags: american-english, punctuation, quotations

In American English, a period is not added at the end of a sentence if it ends with a quote whose last letter is a quotation mark or an exclamation point.

> Edema asked, "Am I an alliteration addict?"

Should the period at the end of the quote be added, if the sentence ends with a question mark or an exclamation point? Is the following sentence correct?

> Did Edema said, "I am an alliteration addict."?

Comment: kiam, another interesting example would be **Did Edema said, "Am I an alliteration addict?"?** :)

Comment: kiam, I thought another **Who shouted, "Long live the king!"?** :)

Comment: In the first case, the second quotation mark is removed; in the second case, both the punctuation marks are left. That is, in American English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you remove the punctuation from the quote, so the period would go away and the question mark would remain. (Also note it should read *Did Edema say*, not *Did Edema said*.)

So the corrected version of the sentence would be:

> Did Edema say "I am an alliteration addict"?